# *Et chacun de se mettre à l'ouvrage.*

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, infinitif, phrase

I am interested in the exact meaning and grammatical structure of the phrase *Et chacun de se mettre à l'ouvrage*, in the fragment from *"Martine fait du théâtre."* below. It seemed to puzzle francophones around me: why not
*Et chacun se met à l'ouvrage.*
or
*Et chacun doit se mettre à l'ouvrage.*

---

[image]

> — Voilà, j'ai trouvé la clef.
>  — Ouvrons le coffre, dit Jean.
> Clic, clac, le couvercle se soulève... Oh ! les beaux rubans, les
> chapeaux de paille, les jolis costumes !
>  Voici des robes, des
> parures, des foulards multicolores.
>  — J'ai une idée : Voulez-vous
> jouer avec moi ? dit Martine. Nous allons faire du théâtre.
>  **Et
> chacun de se mettre à l'ouvrage.**

Comment: Hmm... Implicite : Et je prie chacun de se mettre à l'ouvrage ?

Comment: @LukeSawczak Pas ici mais plutôt : *Tous se mettent alors à l'ouvrage*.

Answer (score 3):

Il s'agit d'un « infinitif de *narration* ou *historique* introduit par *de* (langue littéraire) » (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, § 901) avec le sujet apparaissant avant l'infinitif :

> Je m'écriai : « Voilà notre homme ! » et mes collègues d'APPLAUDIR, et
> le roi D'AGRÉER M. de Damas (Chateaubriand)

On le classe dans la catégorie des infinitifs prédicats de phrase. L'infinitif de narration participait d'un registre familier au 17<sup>e</sup>, parfois sans préposition (« Lors Oudart se revestir [...] ; Chacun rire, tous se préparer », Rabelais, § 901 note H1), alors que le LBU dit de lui « qu'il passe aujourd'hui pour élégant et un peu recherché ». Voir peut-être [ceci](https://www.persee.fr/doc/lfr_0023-8368_2000_num_127_1_997) en réponse à [cela](https://www.cairn.info/l-infinitif-dit-de-narration--9782801112014-page-149.htm) pour une réflexion sur la syntaxe.

Ce genre de construction met en relief la conséquence d'actions antérieures ([BDL](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/24216/la-grammaire/le-verbe/modes/infinitif/emploi-de-linfinitif-dans-divers-types-de-phrases)), ce qui n'est pas nécessairement le cas avec les autres formulations proposées, que pourrait par ailleurs évoquer un [adverbe](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52007/et-chacun-de-se-mettre-%C3%A0-louvrage#comment107914_52007).

---

It is an "infinitif de *narration* ou *historique* introduit par *de* (langue littéraire)" [narrative or historical infinitive introduced by de (literary language)] (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, § 901) with the subject appearing before the infinitive:

> Je m'écriai : « Voilà notre homme ! » et mes collègues d'APPLAUDIR, et
> le roi D'AGRÉER M. de Damas (Chateaubriand)

It is classified in the category of predicate infinitives of a sentence. The narrative infinitive was part of a colloquial register in the 17<sup>th</sup> century, sometimes without a preposition ("Lors Oudart se revestir [...] ; Chacun rire, tous se préparer", Rabelais, § 901 note H1), while the LBU says of it "qu'il passe aujourd'hui pour élégant et un peu recherché" [that it passes today for elegant and a bit refined]. See perhaps [this](https://www.persee.fr/doc/lfr_0023-8368_2000_num_127_1_997) in response to [that](https://www.cairn.info/l-infinitif-dit-de-narration--9782801112014-page-149.htm) for some thoughts concerning syntax.

This kind of construction emphasizes the consequence of previous actions ([BDL](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/24216/la-grammaire/le-verbe/modes/infinitif/emploi-de-linfinitif-dans-divers-types-de-phrases)), which is not necessarily the case with the other proposed phrasings, which might otherwise be evoked by an [adverb](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52007/et-chacun-de-se-mettre-%C3%A0-louvrage#comment107914_52007).